# Change text color from text_area in html and rails

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'd like to know if is it possible to change the color from the text of a text_area in rails, without using css. If there is no possible way, how can iI do it with css?

```
    <div class="">
      <%=f.text_area(:notes_warning,rows:"4",width:"100%")%>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<div class="my-awesome-class">
  <%=f.text_area(:notes_warning,rows:"4",width:"100%")%>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.my-awesome-class textarea {
   color: red;
}
```

Comment: Does that mean there is no other way ?

Comment: They're completely different things. You can not modify your page with rails. Rails s a back-end development library, you have to use css to change color, sizes, fonts etc.